# Xamarin form app using functionality from native libraries

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-binding

The only platform-specific code in my app comes from native libraries. So I see two options:

**1.** iOS and Android projects referencing their appropriate bindings. This would require both of them to handle UI events that require these platform-dependent libraries.

**2.** Create a Shared Project that would create wrappers around binding projects to create a uniform API and then use compiler directives to choose appropriate implementation.

I'm uncertain if the first option is achievable: handling UI events natively and returning shared response back to the cross-platform xamarin forms project for further processing.

I believe in the second option, both apps would contain ALL code. I also do not know if I can use a Shared Project if I already use .NET Standard code sharing strategy(required as .NET standard does not support compiler directives).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm uncertain if the first option is achievable: handling UI events natively and returning shared response back to the cross-platform xamarin forms project for further processing.

It is achievable,  as all the forms' Controls are rendered into native through renderers. You can only access the native control through [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). And for returning shared response back to the forms project, you can achieve that through Custom Events on Custom controls just like [Cusom ListView Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview/)'s `ItemSelected` Event:

In PCL:

```
public class NativeListView : ListView
{
  ...
  public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;
  ...
}
```

In Custom Renderer:

```
Control.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

...
void OnItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ((NativeListView)Element).NotifyItemSelected(((NativeListView)Element).Items.ToList()[e.Position - 1]);
}
```

**But if you have lots of plaform-specific functionality in your project. Using Shared Project is a good option.**

> I also do not know if I can use a Shared Project if I already use .NET Standard code sharing strategy(required as .NET standard does not support compiler directives).

I believe what you need is to change your `PCL` project into a Shared project. Of course some codes modifications are necessary. But that won't be much. If you mean you want your `PCL` to reference a new `Shared Project`. No, I don't think it will work.